# how to update looping form in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have a problem where i want to update a looping form in codeigniter 3. in column nik_pindah where have a id_surat is same

---MY CONTROLLER WITH FORM VALIDATION---

```
public function update_nik_pindah_kelurahan($id_surat_pindah){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');    
    $i = 0; // untuk loopingnya
    $a = $this->input->post('nik_pindah');
    if ($a[0] !== null){
        foreach ($a as $row => $val){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("nik_pindah[$i]","nik_pindah", "integer|callback_nik_pindah_available");
    }
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Mohon isi %s terlebih dahulu');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('integer', 'Isi %s hanya menggunakan angka');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $this->edit_nik_pindah_kelurahan($id_surat_pindah);
    } else {
    $id_surat_pindah = $this->input->post('id_surat_pindah');
    $id_surat    = $this->input->post('id_surat');
    $i       = 0; // untuk loopingnya
        $a       = $this->input->post('nik_pindah');            
        if ($a[0] !== null) {
            $data = array(
        'id_surat'    => $id_surat,             
        'id_surat_pindah' => $id_surat_pindah
             );
            foreach ($a as $row) {
                $dataaa = [             
            'id_surat'  => $id_surat_pindah,
            'nik_pindah'    =>$row,
        ];
                $wheree = array(
            'id_surat' => $id_surat_pindah
        );
                $this->db->where('id_surat', $id_surat_pindah);
        $update = $this->db->update('nik_pindah', $dataaa);
        if ($update) {
                $i++;
        }
    }
        $where = array(
        'id_surat_pindah' => $id_surat_pindah
    );
        $this->m_pindah_kelurahan->update_data($where, $data, 'surat_pindah');
    }
    redirect('admin_pindah_kelurahan/index');
}
}
```

---MY CONTROLLER WITHOUT FORM VALIDATION---

```
public function update_nik_pindah_kelurahan($id_surat_pindah){
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $id_surat_pindah = $this->input->post('id_surat_pindah');
    $id_surat    = $this->input->post('id_surat');
    $i       = 0; // untuk loopingnya
        $a       = $this->input->post('nik_pindah');        
        if ($a[0] !== null) {
            $data = array(
            'id_surat'          => $id_surat,               
        'id_surat_pindah'   => $id_surat_pindah
        );
            foreach ($a as $row){
                $dataaa = [             
            'id_surat'  => $id_surat_pindah,
             'nik_pindah'   =>$row,
            ];
            $wheree = array(
        'id_surat' => $id_surat_pindah
        );
            $this->db->where('id_surat', $id_surat_pindah);
            $update = $this->db->update('nik_pindah', $dataaa);
            if ($update) {
         $i++;
            }
    }
        $where = array(
        'id_surat_pindah' => $id_surat_pindah
    );
        $this->m_pindah_kelurahan->update_data($where, $data, 'surat_pindah');
}
redirect('admin_pindah_kelurahan/index');
}
}
```

---MY VIEWS---

```
<?php 
  foreach ($nik_pindah_kelurahan as $np) :
    if (empty($np->nik_pindah)) { ?>
       <input type="text" name="nik_pindah" class="form-control" value="belum tersedia"><br>
    <?php } else {?>            
       <input type="text" name="nik_pindah[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $np->nik_pindah ?>"><br>
  <?php } endforeach; ?>
```

If with or without form validation will updating data but all column where id_surat is same (not particular value)

like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub8zz.png) then [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p73oq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Everytime the `foreach` makes a loop, `$this->db->where()` has the same condition because `$id_surat_pindah` has always the same value, so you're updating the same rows once and once again. Also (if I understand it correctly), keep in mind that if `$id_surat_pindah` is not a unique key, everytime you make an UPDATE all the rows with its value will be affected.

Otherwise, I would recommend you to check your code using `update_batch()` instead the loop: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update_batch